# Is there a free API to retrieve artist images for applications

Tags: android, last.fm, google-custom-search

I was hoping to use Google Custom Search but they limit you to 100 queries per day...and that is per API key so the total queries per day for ALL users of my app would be 100. That is pretty sad honestly.

LastFM won't allow you to use artist images in a commercial application and MusicBrainz only offers album images, not artist images. Does anyone know another source?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would look into Freebase. Just doing a few quick searches there, it seems like they have images for artists, though it will vary a bit based on what was uploaded (could be an image of them at a concert, for instance).

That being said, if Freebase works for you they have very lenient API Requests, and offer a lot of control over what is being requested if you familiarize yourself with the queries.

Answer (score 1):

you can check Echo Nest Api for artists. see link [here](http://developer.echonest.com/docs/v4/artist.html)